# What classes may require *_ACCOUNTS, and related permissions?

Tags: android, user-accounts

I'm cleaning up the code of an app that requests the following in its manifest:
android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS
android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS
android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS
android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS
android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL

The question is: what classes/packages imports should I look for when searching for what might possibly be asking for these?

I've already searched for AccountManager - no hits. It is possible that they are no longer needed, but I wish to know the point at which I can be certain.

**[EDIT]** Lint settings to help find this would be even better. Here are mine:
[image]

I see no "missing permissions" option.
If I remove all permissions including all network, READ_PHONE_STATE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, app builds, starts, then WifiManager.getWifiState crashes with a ACCESS_WIFI_STATE-related SecurityException.

**[EDIT2]** The "type mismatches" check is enabled. [Not every version](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/c5d1c6d/core/java/android/accounts/AccountManager.java) of Android used the @RequiresPermission annotation.
[image]

My config: compile SDK version 23, min 14, target 22, build tools version 25.0.1

Comment: if you just remove the permissions from the manifest you should get some lint warnings where you need the permissions, i guess

Comment: @lelloman I don't see any. See edit.

Answer (score 1):

I just made a try, and you should indeed get a warning for missing permissions. Actually it's not even a warning but an error. The option is in `Settings -> Editor -> Inspections -> Android -> Constant and Resource Type Mismatches`, if you read the description you will see something like

> Calling a method that requires a permission without having declared
>   that permission in the manifest

This on AS 2.2.3

UPDATE:

I just checked on a project with compile sdk 23, and in the source code of AccountManager there actually is `@RequiresPermission`

Comment: Sounds like exactly what I need. Odd if it's not on by default. Thank you, I'll get back to this on Monday.

Comment: OK, I have it enabled and set to "ERROR", but it never triggers, even on a test app which needs INTERNET, CAMERA and CALL_PHONE. 

I'm betting on lack of @RequiresPermission annotations. Question updated. Any idea what else I need?

Comment: hum, it still sounds weird, check [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations.html#indirect-permissions), @RequiresPermission is not actually required for the exact method you're calling.